# Is there any way to prevent an pop-up on any third-party apps on macOS (11.0.1)?

Tags: mac, big-sur

After I bought an M1 MacBook and install iCleanmemory which I had used on other macs, I found that whenever the memory reaches a threshold, the pop-up shows up and I am forced to click OK to erase it.

This has not happened in my previous macs and there seems no setting on the app's preferences section to change the behavior. I'm not even sure why this happens, but anyway since it is so tedious to click it I would like to know if there is any way to prevent the pop-up on iCleanmemory, or more broadly, on any apps using system-level setting.

[image]

Comment: I'd consider just uninstalling this snake oil instead. Empty RAM is wasted RAM. The Mac does a really really good job of handling memory, all by itself. It needs no "help" from this type of app at all. the only thing it can possibly do is slow down your Mac, by releasing cached RAM that the Mac thought should be there… so next time it needs it, it has to go fetch it from disk again, slowing the whole thing sown.

Comment: @Tetsujin I see. Is this true from the (relatively) recent version of macOS? I don't understand then why Apple allows the developers to sell the apps on the store.

Comment: This is true for just about any OS in at least the past decade, but the Mac has always been particularly good at it compared to some we might mention;) You'd have to ask Apple why they don't actively prevent snake oil apps.. maybe they consider user choice to be a valid criterion.

Comment: In addition to what Tetsujin says, this tool was last updated on "Sep 27, 2011". Even if it might have been more than snake oil back then it didn't evolve while macOS and the way memory gets managed did.

Comment: https://www.cnet.com/news/memory-cleaning-utilities-not-the-panacea-they-claim-to-be/ might be of interest as well

Answer (score -1):

What you're calling "pop-up" are Notifications. They can be controlled for all apps that offer them in the Notifications Preference Pane of System Preferences.

Comment: Isn't it what shows on the top-right of the screen? This popup shows on any place in the entire screen. Plus, there is no iCleanmemory tab on the Notifications list.

Comment: The preferences pane on my new mac and old one are set in the same way, so I wonder why only my M1 mac keeps showing the popup.

Comment: Could be time to call on vendor support.

Comment: It doesn't look like a Notification alert to me, it looks like a modal dialog. To switch it off, you'd have to find if there's a switch in the app itself.

Comment: @Tetsujin So you mean there is no system-level setting on macOS an end-user can set that prevents it from showing? Maybe could you write it in an answer (which I'm willing to accept)?

Comment: tbh, having never seen Big Sur in operation, I'm not certain enough to provide an answer. As the entire app is well-lubed snake oil, uninstalling it will fix all the problems you have with it ;)